# Why can't I get the selected items in the CListBox? MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, clistbox

I have an MFC dialog with a CListBox on it. I'm able to successfully add items to it using `CListBox::AddString` and set data pointers using `CListBox::SetItemDataPtr`. The strings show in the listbox and I can retrieve the data pointers by calling `CListBox::GetItemDataPtr` and passing in a static index. I'm not able to the get the selected index using `ClistBox::GetSelItems`. I followed the example on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds24bscf.aspx and even tried using LPINT:

```
LPINT selItem = new int;
m_Lb_Avail_Cmnds.GetSelItems(1, selItem); //m_Lb_Avail_Cmnds is a CListBox
int i = *selItem;
```

But it's always returning 0 despite which item is selected.

Comment: GetSelItems is only valid for multiple-selection list box(s).  Is your list box multi or single select?  Use GetCurSel for single selection list box(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a single-selection listbox (that I am guessing you're using because you call `GetSelItems` with `nMaxItems` set to `1`), `GetSelItems` is not supported. Use `GetCurSel`  instead:

```
int i = m_Lb_Avail_Cmnds.GetCurSel();
```